# How to change the refresh rate at which the network manager updates the wireless access points

Tags: 11.04, wireless

Sometimes it takes too long for the network manager to update to see new wireless AP. Is it possible to change the time interval between checks?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "refresh rate" (scan interval) is hardcoded in the source code of network manager. The interval is some value between 20 and 120 seconds. Some heuristics decide when to scan more often and when less often. There seems to be no way to configure the interval other than patching the source and compiling.

See the [relevant source file of network manager version 0.9.0](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/src/nm-device-wifi.c?id=0.9.0) and search for interval.

There is a lot of discussion on the internet about allowing users to change the interval. The developers do not want that. They argue that users might set the interval too low and that will cause grievance for all members of the wireless network, not only for the user alone.

I am sorry I cannot provide you a link to that discussion. I forgot to save the link and now I couldn't find it again. You will have to take my word for it.

So it is not possible to configure the refresh rates, and it seems that it will not happen anytime soon.

---

You can trigger a scan manually using the following command:

```
sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

Replace `eth1` with the name of your wireless device. Use `iwconfig` to find out the name of your wireless device.

You can list the found networks using `nm-tool`.

You can observe the activity of your wireless device using `iwevent`.

Comment: Or you could just throw the above command in a script and setup a cron job to have it run every minute if you wanted it to run that frequent.

Comment: @Justin: How do you enter a sudo command to a CRON job so that it runs without asking for a root password?

Comment: What it really should do is that if you click the AppIndicator it should scan then. I think that is what the Apple guys arrived at. I have to think someone would have forked this and added this functionality.

Comment: Some links to some of the discussions mentioned would be very helpful.

Comment: @RichardRodriguez, simply setup the crontab of 'root', not of the user.  Bypass sudo this way.

Comment: Here are two lengthy bug reports with the related discussions:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766482
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=513820

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by lesmana, will not guarantee and immediate connection because it does not change the
polling interval. The command simply shows a list of
networks already polled at a given time and cached.

A better solution should be

`sudo service NetworkManager stop`

`sudo service NetworkManager start`

This would immediately refresh all new and available wireless networks.
Hope this helps some-one