# How to change wifi refresh time

Tags: 12.10, wireless

The wireless network manager in my `Ubuntu 12.10` respond pretty late to the change in wifi network(s) i.e even when sometime switch my wifi ON or OFF it doesn't shows them for quite a time.Whereas same network(s) when changed,is showed pretty quickly in my friends laptop which has windows 7 on it.

So what can I do to change my wireless network refresh time so that it responds a bit faster.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/53498/how-to-change-the-refresh-rate-at-which-the-network-manager-updates-the-wireless ;)

Comment: Oh yea sorry my bad :(