# Adjust timeperiod for background scanning?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, network-monitoring, wpa-supplicant

is it possible to adjust the automatic background scanning timeperiod?
I want to decrease the time period.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you asking about exactly ? What do you mean "decrease the time period"?

Comment: I want to scan for new networks every 1s or something like this.
The NetworkManager is scanning for new networks every 30s or 1m or I don't know the exact time. ^^

Comment: As far as I know you would have to recompile network manager as the scan time is hard coded. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/53498/how-to-change-the-refresh-rate-at-which-the-network-manager-updates-the-wireless

Comment: that's exactly I was looking for! thanks. :)
interesting that the developers don't want that...

Comment: @Nick: It's more likely that the developers didn't think that this would be a useful enough feature and nobody filed a feature request yet that gained much traction.