# Output of `nmcli device wifi list` is often nearly empty on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: network-manager

When I moved from Ubuntu 14.04, to Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that often the output of `nmcli d wifi` would, instead of listing a bunch of visible access points, only lists the access point that the computer is connected to.

An example of this looks like:

```
me@computer:~$ sudo nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  SSID  MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY 
*       XYZ   Infra  161   540 Mbit/s  67      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```

This can be "fixed" by manually invoking `sudo iw wlan0 scan`, and then re-running the above and seeing the nearby APs as expected.

My understanding is that periodically, the system is doing scans automatically (every 300s, if I recall correctly from past research). It seems as if in the meantime, Ubuntu/NetworkManager is deciding to discard what it knows from the last scan.

**Is this a known change, and/or a feature, or a bug?**  Can this be changed?  When researching, I regularly [end up at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53498/how-to-change-the-refresh-rate-at-which-the-network-manager-updates-the-wireless), which suggests that the scan frequency is driven by NetworkManager and is hardcoded.

---

So far, I have seen this behavior with the Intel 7260, 8260, and 9260 wifi cards, as well as an Atheros wifi card, so I am fairly certain this is not a hardware issue.  The system I'm looking at at the moment has network-manager 1.10.6

To demonstrate whether this apparent cache-clearing is happening on a given system, one approach is to monitor the output of this command: `while [ 1 ]; do nmcli device wifi list | wc -l; sleep 15; done`.  When the symptom occurs described above, the output will be "2".  If you do a new scan while the command is running, i.e. `iw wlan0 scan`, the output will reflect that NetworkManage is now aware of other access points.

On the two machines I've tested the above with, I am consistently seeing 17x 15 second intervals before the cache is cleared, so that's a cache lifetime of ~255-280 seconds.  Of note is this doesn't match the 120 s in [the link from above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53498/how-to-change-the-refresh-rate-at-which-the-network-manager-updates-the-wireless) (which I confirmed remains unchanged in the current github repo).

Comment: Is this more what you expect? `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: You got my hopes up, but alas, as in 14.04, `nmcli device wifi` defaults to the `list` subcommand.  Updating the question to remove this point of confusion. (for ref: I initially gave the example with `nmcli d wifi`)

Comment: Reading the nmcli man page on a 19.10 machine, I saw that there is a `nmcli d wifi list --rescan [auto|yes|no]` option listed. This would be interesting to play with, but is not a feature in 18.04.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update/Note: I haven't dug into commit history, but it appears the scan interval changed back with 20.04's version of NetworkManager, to something a bit more reasonable, on the order of every 4 minutes (I might be misrecalling this number).

---

So this is a side effect of a [intentional change made to NetworkManager](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/commit/fd6ddcc794949ded253dde063fcbddc35054081b).

Previously, NetworkManager would do periodic scans regardless of quality of wifi connection. This [caused issues for common usecases](http://blog.cerowrt.org/post/disabling_channel_scans/), such as videoconferencing.

At the time of this writing, the logic has been tweaked so that the time between scans (on common WPA2 setups) is *once-per-day*, as long as the signal strength is good, in this case, > 70/100 (seemingly arbitrary units used by NM).  If the signal strength is below this threshold, scans will occur *every 30s* until a better connection is established.  This is [Network Manager's hardcoded setting](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2018-May/msg00017.html) of the bgscan roam threshold belonging to the underlying wpa_supplicant. ([Approximate link to current version of this code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/-/blob/master/src/supplicant/nm-supplicant-config.c#L583-604))

I didn't dig further, but evidently, `nmcli device wifi list` is loading cached information about what wifi networks are available. It seems reasonable to me (now that I understand more of what's going on) that this cache is discarded when it reaches some staleness threshold, and thus no other APs/networks are listed.

---

So this question resulted from observation of a symptom of this change on a machine in a static environment.  And for the vast majority of realworld usecases, it's harmless. Had I moved to an area served better by a different AP, my laptop would have roamed without my noticing, probably.

What about for a machine moving around continually, needing to jump from AP to AP quickly? It might work, but that depends. Ultimately, that's not the designed for use-case here, and the above logic is hardcoded, and not tweakable.